# Where is the implemantion of `Context.registerReceiver()`

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, observer-pattern

I wanted to know how Google implemented the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for their broadcast receivers. So I dug into their code and I found a method definition and a implementation.

Definition in class **`Context`**:

```
@Nullable
public abstract Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter);
```

Implementation in class **`ContextWrapper`**:

```
Context mBase;

@Override
public Intent registerReceiver(
    BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    return mBase.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

So the only thing that the implementation of the abstract method `registerReceiver` does, is to call itself on a `Context` object again?

But where is the actual magic? Where is the code that really implements that abstract method? What am I missing?

Regards, winklerrr

Comment: "What am I missing?" -- you are missing [`ContextImpl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java), which is basically where the "real" `Context` default implementation lies. However, with respect to broadcasts, `ContextImpl` is of little use. The observer pattern is handled a core OS process, not in `ContextImpl`. After all, broadcasts are IPC. If you want a local in-process observer pattern, there are better things to look at.

Comment: @CommonsWare but why didn't I find the implementation when I used Android Studios `goTo` functionality?

Comment: Because that would go to something like `Context`. The whole `Context` setup is kinda screwy.